# Firebase onCall Function with Multiple Parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I send **two string values** to a specific cloud function.

Here is an example of how I send one string to the **onCall** function.

**index.js** onCall() cloud function

```
exports.updateUserPassword = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const uid = data.text;

});
```

**authentication.js** in project root directory (calling the onCall cloud function)

```
var updateUserPassword  = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('updateUserPassword ');

updateUserPassword({text: uid}).then(function(result) {

    var userProperties = result.data.userData;
    var successfulPasswordChange = userProperties.uid;

})
```

How can I implement a way to send and receive a second string value.

Assuming modifications will need to be in the calling function.

```
({text: uid}) //ex psuedo {text: uid, text: password}
```

Also how to retrieve it in the onCall() function with

```
var uid = data.text;
var password = data.text;
```

Comment: Have you tried what you're suggesting?  It looks like it would work.  If it's not, please post the exact code that isn't working, along with your debugging information.

Comment: the code works fine. I just dont know how to add two string elements in the calling function or how to properly assign them in the onCall() function.

Comment: As I said, it looks like you're on the right track.  You should definitely just try your ideas first before posting.  Then if it doesn't work, post what isn't working, along with your debugging details.

Comment: I would really like to help you, but first I need to understand where exactly you are stuck. Because you don't sound stuck.  It seems like you know what you're doing.  I would like to understand what isn't working the way you expect with the code you've written.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is some confusion on what you can send to your function and what that object looks like.

ANY data you send will be in an object, you aren't bound by `data.text` you can pass any JSON object as `data`
So your example:

```
var myData = {
    uid: "12345",
    newPassword: "one2three4",
    favoriteColor: "blue"
}
updateUserPassword(myData).then(function(result) {
    // ...
})
```

Then in your function:

```
exports.updatePassword = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  var newPassword = data.newPassword;
  var uid = data.uid;
  var favoriteColor = data.favoriteColor;
  // ... do whatever
});
```

Other important things to note..

1. You dont need to pass the UID Manually in a callable cloud function you can get it from the context like: `const uid = context.auth.uid;` [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function)
2. I would be hesitant to have a simple overwritable method to change a users password, although you can do it with the [firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password)
3. I would instead consider triggering a reset and using the [firebase password reset email flow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email)..

Comment: Dennis thank you for your input. The purpose of password change is for customizability without the email being sent.